# Class variables in OnClickListener

Tags: android, onclick, sharedpreferences, onclicklistener, class-variables

I have a separate class for my OnClickListeners. I would like to add items to an arraylist when i click a button, and remove them when I click a 2nd time. I have the framework here:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        Button button = (Button)v;
        if(isClicked) {
            button.setText("Enabled");
            Log.v("Spirit: ", v.getTag() + "");
            spirits_list.add(v.getTag() + "");
            isClicked = false;
        } else {
            button.setText("Disabled");
            spirits_list.remove(v.getId()-1);
            isClicked = true;
        }



    }
```

I also have an ArrayList initialized at the top, but every time I click a button it reinitializes the ArrayList. How can I get around this? Also, I need to be able to save the ArrayList to SharedPreferences - how can I do this from my OnClickListener?

Comment: SharedPreferences can store key-value pairs of primitive types. For an  ArrayList you can probably create a new SharedPreference XML by the name of your ArrayList, and store the entries as key-value pairs with their index as the key. (I'm not sure that's a very good practice though)

Comment: Storing an ArrayList in SharedPreferences isn't the problem. It's not liking my SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(NAME, 0);

Comment: @Nelson.b.austin : if you want to create getSharedPreferences from non activity class then you will need to pass Activity context to non activity class and access getSharedPreferences method as `SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(NAME, 0);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use your own class, you can pass all the goodness around in class members:

```
class MyListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ArrayList<Object> spirits_list;
    private Context ctx;

    public MyListener( Context ctx, ArrayList<Object> list ) {
        super();
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.spirits_list = list;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Button button = (Button)v;
        if(isClicked) {
            button.setText("Enabled");
            Log.v("Spirit: ", v.getTag() + "");
            this.spirits_list.add(v.getTag() + "");
            isClicked = false;
        } else {
            button.setText("Disabled");
            this.spirits_list.remove(v.getId()-1);
            isClicked = true;
        }



    }

}
```

The context will allow you to access SharedPrefs as well. You can then invoke this bit as follows:

```
view.setOnClickListener( new MyListener( this, spirits_list ) );
```

Comment: Thanks! So how do I return that list to my Main Activity?

Comment: Sure thing. Since you're passing in the list, any changes to the list will affect the list in your activity. No need to pass it back.

Comment: Gotcha. That's awesome! I had my Log just laying in the Activity. I added a button that iterated through the ArrayList and sure enough, there it was! Thanks